# An abstract subclass of OrderedDict? python3

Tags: python-3.x, collections, abstract-class, abc

A subclass that subclasses ABC and OrderedDict does not act as a true abstract class:

```
>>> from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> class AbstractOrderedDict(OrderedDict, ABC):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def abstract_method(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> AbstractOrderedDict()
AbstractOrderedDict()
```

One would expect an instantiation of AbstractOrderedDict to fail, right?

Further experimentation showed that subclassing `object` and `ABC` raises a TypeError on instantiation, as expected (obviously), but subclassing any other basic class (dict, int, list, etc.) does not (behaves as above).

Questions:

1. Why does it behave this way?
2. Is it a bad idea, in theory, to make an abstract subclass of OrderedDict (or others)?

   1. Why?
   2. Alternatives?

Comment: I have just now created a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407909/why-doesnt-the-abc-abcmeta-abstract-instantiation-check-work-on-derivatives-of) without realizing that you had posted the same question. I am going to let that one sit because of some other info I have added.

Comment: Yours got more traction :) I'm glad you asked it and let me know here.